# Pyspark: sum column values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have this RDD (showing two elements):

```
[['a', [1, 2]], ['b', [3, 0]]]
```

and I'd like to add up elements in the list based on the index, so to have
a final result

```
[4, 2]
```

how would I achieve this? I know the presence of first element ('a'/'b') is irrelevant as I could strip it out with a map so the question becomes how to sum column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip the keys as you said, and then reduce your RDD as follows (given that you have 2 columns):

```
myRDD.reduce(lambda x,y:[x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]])
```

This will give you the sum of all the columns

Answer (score 2):

```
$ pyspark
>>> x = [['a', [1, 2]], ['b', [3, 0]]]
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(x)
>>> rdd.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduce(lambda x,y: [sum(i) for i in zip(x, y)])
```